# how to create application layer (server ) in java

Tags: java, android, web-applications

I am building an android app and i have following doubts:-

1. I need help in how to create back end that is server (application layer).(I am good in java . so if you could guide me a way using java that would be nice)
2. I need know how to connect the server to my app both on app and on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on you're needs but you're best bet is using something like Django, Ruby on Rails or Python.

[Building Awesome Rails API's Part 1](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2013/06/13/building-awesome-rails-apis-part-1/)

Comment: sir can you give way to use python to make server for app

Comment: @NitishMowall Sure! Check out this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm if you follow this, you'll have you're Python server in under 10 minutes. In order to communicate with the server to have to work with sockets: http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Java, there are more ways. Here is one of them (pretty common these days). Your backend app could be a spring based and use REST controllers as the endpoints. There are plenty of introductions, e.g. http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service . Once you have established and run the backend app (either deployment to a web server or spring boot - see http://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) you can connect to the server via TCP/IP. Your android app could use http-client.